# selenium python not storing data in file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

made a bot using selenium python to scrape the information, it takes the input from an excel file and goes to quillbot website and converts and should store in same excel file in another sheet.

Code link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hnCUoTbW7e20TjAv2dI-a6Uc3sytX3hD?usp=sharing

**The error**
[image: error image]

**CODE:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import time

file=pd.read_excel('E:\sabudh INTERNSHIPps2\seleniumbot\sampledata.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
n = (len(file['sentence']))
sentences1 = []
sentences2 = []
sentences3 = []
sentences4 = []
sentences5 = []



driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://quillbot.com/")

for i in range(4):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputText"]')
    element.send_keys(file['sentence'][i])

    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button/span/div')
    action = ActionChains(driver).click(on_element = element).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editable-content-within-article~0"]/div')
    print('1st')
    print(element.text)
    sentences1.append(element.text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]')
    action = ActionChains(driver).click(on_element = element).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editable-content-within-article~0"]/div')
    print('2nd')
    print(element.text)
    sentences2.append(element.text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]')
    action = ActionChains(driver).click(on_element = element).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editable-content-within-article~0"]/div')
    sentences3.append(element.text)
    print('3rd')
    print(element.text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]')
    action = ActionChains(driver).click(on_element = element).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editable-content-within-article~0"]/div')
    print('4th')
    print(element.text)
    sentences4.append(element.text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]')
    action = ActionChains(driver).click(on_element = element).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editable-content-within-article~0"]/div')
    sentences5.append(element.text)
    print('5th')
    print(element.text)
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.refresh()

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['1st Reframed sentences'] = sentences1
df['2nd Reframed sentences'] = sentences2
df['3rd Reframed sentences'] = sentences3
df['4th Reframed sentences'] = sentences4
df['5th Reframed sentences'] = sentences5

df.index += 1

print(df)

with pd.ExcelWriter('sampledata.xlsx') as writer:
    writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook('E:\sabudh INTERNSHIP ps2\seleniumbot\sampledata.xlsx')
    df.to_excel ('sampledata.xlsx', sheet_name="rephrase1", startcol=0, startrow=0)

driver.close()
```

I hope I've written all the code and indentation correctly. But it is showing `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` even I have viewed many articles and stackoverflow questions not solved

Comment: Post your code and full traceback here and not as links to different sites. Ideally, post a [mre].

Comment: You did not include the full traceback. And reduce the code to a [mre]